# How is this code not solving ABA problem?

Tags: c++, concurrency, atomic

I trying to learn about the ABA problem in a lock free stack. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABA_problem):

We have a stack A,B,C.

- thread_1 tries to pop A. Reads the old_value as A and next value as B. Before thread_1 starts the cas loop:
- thread_2 comes in and pops A, then
- thread_3 comes in and pops B, then
- thread_4 comes in and pushes A.
- the stack is now A,C. thread_1 resumes and sees A and sets the head to B instead of C. There you go, data corruption. B doesn't exist, it got deleted by thread B.

I have the following implementation:

```
class Stack
{
    struct Node { Node* next; };
    std::atomic<Node*> head;
public:

    void push()
    {
        auto node = new Node{ head.load() };
        while(!head.compare_exchange_weak(node->next, node));
    }

    void pop()
    {
        auto old_head = head.load();
        while(!head.compare_exchange_weak(old_head, old_head->next));
    }
};
```

I know that this implementation is not solving the ABA problem but I can't figure out why. I've looked at the assembly [code](https://godbolt.org/z/aGGrvx):

PUSH

```
mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdx]
$LL2@push:
   lock cmpxchg QWORD PTR [rbx], rdx
   je      SHORT $LN18@push [to exit the function]
   mov     QWORD PTR [rdx], rax <----- **AFTER** the CAS the head->next pointer is loaded
   jmp     SHORT $LL2@push
```

POP

```
mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rcx]
$LL2@pop:
   mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rax]  <----- **BEFORE** the CAS the head->next pointer is loaded
   lock cmpxchg QWORD PTR [rcx], rdx
   jne     SHORT $LL2@pop
```

The assembly code seems to load the old_head->next pointer before the CAS is executed. So when thread_1 resumes it just loads the correct next pointer to C and **this code appears to solve the ABA problem**. The problem must be somewhere else and I can't find it.

Comment: Your code has memory leaks.  There is no `delete`.  Therefore, your "B doesn't exist" scenario never happens.  If you fix this memory leak and delete nodes that are popped, your access to `old_head->next` is now a memory race.  You could be reading memory you no longer own.

Comment: that's the thing. If I look at the assembly the old_head->next is loaded first and then it checks whether old_head is equal to head, then it correctly sets the pointer to C not B [the one that was deleted]. PS: I removed the deletes for simplicity's sake :)

Comment: Your understanding of the ABA problem appears to be incomplete.  You also state that your solution to it is incomplete.  I could show how the ABA problem is not solved here, but it involves code that you have omitted from the question.  The simplest explanation I can give is that ABA describes two objects "A" that appear to be the same, but are not.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation does not work for some reasons.
First, this implementation is wrong because if CAS fails you have to update node so that it points to the new head:

```
auto node = new Node{ head.load() };
while(!head.compare_exchange_weak(node->next, node)){ node->next = head.load() }
```

push() has a similar bug.

Secondly, your solution is only ABA prone if Nodes are freed. This can be proved because by definition ABA requires that A can be somehow "reinserted" into the data structure. Because your values (A and B) are pointers, if you never free a Node the memory location containing that node (A) will never be reallocated. This means that during the execution of your program A can only occur once, and therefore ABA is impossible.
This "solution" has many obvious limitations such as memory leaks, but it does indeed solve ABA.
If you do not assume that nodes are never freed, your solution is ABA prone because of executions like the one you specified.